# Can we disable mipmapping at the render?

Tags: texturing

When I disable mipmapping in the user preferences, it doesn't work in the 3D render. Can you help me please?

Comment: It does'n work :/

Comment: What do you mean? The answer I put? If so, then I'll add to it. But it's better if you place comments to my answer on my answer... or maybe the rep is getting in the way, that's annoying.

Comment: I've edited my answer, if you give more detail, add some images or maybe even post the [.blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) I could assist better.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think we just need to duplicate the image "duplicate the number of pixels"

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable "GPU Mipmap Generation" as well. Without it disabled, the mipmap will just generate using GPU, instead of CPU.

[image: GPU Mipmap Generation]

As with many other elements of Blender, there is an option to toggle mipmapping in properties as well as user preferences. Go to properties> Texture> Image Sampling. (The image below is as it appears in Blender Render.)

[image: GPU Mipmap in properties]